# InfoPath GetUserProfileByName doesn't fill in existing Forms

Tags: infopath, soap, infopath-data-connections, forms-library

I created my data connection to the udcx and it works like a charm for new entries but will not fill in the nodes for an existing form people picker field. This is InfoPath 2013 on a SharePoint 2016 form library.

Thanks in advance.